# Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a csv, add columns and then set values for each cell in the new columns. but I can the below error

```
 raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

My csv data does not have any index column, I don't know how add an incremental numeric index column to it.

I tried `print("data.columns = ", data.columns)` but I can see all of the columns are part of the index which is incorrect.

```
data = pd.read_csv( filename, names=colnames, header=None )
# data = data.drop(['datetime'], axis=1)
data[ "positive" ] = 0
data[ "negative" ] = 0
data[ "hate_speech" ] = 0
data[ "neither" ] = 0
data[ "count" ] = 0
data[ "class" ] = -1
print("data.columns = ", data.columns)
for j in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    tweet_set = set( str(data[ "tweet" ][ j ]).split() )

    pos_count = len(pos_set.intersection( tweet_set ))
    data.at[ j , "positive"] = pos_count
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [reset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) the index:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
```